# R statistics on Ubuntu 16.04 lts: copy and paste does not work

Tags: command-line, 16.04, statistical

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on 2 different machines. On both I have this problem:
I open a terminal, call for R statistics, copy my code from any file (txt, doc, xls, csv, it's all the same), paste it on R (on the terminal) and what is pasted differs from what I copied.
In particular, some letters or numbers are repeatedly pasted.

EG: I copy: load("Travel2015.RData")
It pastes: load("Trrravvvvel2015.RData.RData")

As the problem occurs on both machines, independently from the 'source' file and the code, as the code works fine on Windows... maybe it is a bug, isn't it?